# Can't run Yeoman (yo) as sudo

Tags: vagrant, yeoman

I installed [this](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/arvindr21/boxes/mean-box) vagrant box (1.3k downloads, so I'm assuming is a good one) that comes pre-installed with the MEAN stack.

I tried running `yo meanjs` but it doesn't have necessary permissions to write on folders, so I tried `sudo yo meanjs` and it crashes with the followig error:

```
Error: EACCES, permission denied '/home/vagrant/.config/configstore/insight-yo.yml'
You don't have access to this file.
```

I'm relatively new to MEAN stack, but as far as I know, root usually have unlimited power, so why could this be happening, am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this box working, but there are some things I had to change in the vagrant file, and do in the box itself.

### The Vagrant File

```ruby
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

  config.vm.box = "arvindr21/mean-box"
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 8080, host: 8080
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 2000
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 3000, host:3000

  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
      # Update Stuff
      # =======================================
      apt-get -y update

      # Folder Sync
      # =======================================
      echo "Folder Sync"
      if ! [ -L /var/www ]; then
        rm -rf /var/www
        ln -fs /vagrant /var/www
      fi
  SHELL

end
```

### In the Box

- To get inside your box you'll need to do `vagrant ssh`.
- Then change directory to your vagrant folder, which will actually be sym link to the folder your working from.  `cd /vagrant`
- Follow this with `yo meanjs`
- You will get errors because not all dependencies are directly installed from your NPM.
- The JSON file is so right after this step your going to run sudo npm install which will get all the dependencies.  It will take a while to install.
- Finally your ready to do a `grunt` to get your application running on port 3000. It will take a while and you'll see an error node env is not defined, but the app will run as expected on localhost:3000

Hope that helps.